# Отправляются ли скрытые данные из формы HTML?

Tags: html, css, формы

Будут ли отправлены на сервер input'ы, которые лежат в `<form></form>`, но имеют `display: none`?

Comment: Да, для этого использовать можно <input type="hidden" name="varname" value="Yes"> - http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/skrytoe-pole

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, отправляются, так как внешний вид input-ов не влияет на то, будут ли отправлены или нет.

Впрочем для данных целей — отправки скрытых полей, обычно используют `<input type="hidden">`, а не скрывают их с помощью CSS, ибо если правила CSS будут отключены в браузере, то и все скрытые поля будут видны пользователю, с type=hidden такого не произойдёт.

Comment: Да, спасибо) 
Мне нужен именно css, ибо должны быть задействованы модальные окна в форме.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, если этот ответ Вам помог, то отметьте его как правильный.

Comment: прошу заметить, что отключенные `disabled` поля ввода по прежнему не будут отправляться